# apache log4j not taking properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I want to create a new log file for each day and I am using apache log4j. But it is not working as expected. Here is my project structure.

[image]

My log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=app.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

But it is not even creating a log file. I also tried to put just below properties in my application.properties file but it just create a single file called application.log. Look like second properties configuration is not taking at all.

```
logging.file.name=application.log
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
```

Finally here is my imports

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

Dont know which is the right way and if so why it is not working.  A help would be greately appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Second config property is to say that create new logfile and logfile name should include date on change of date

```
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
```

so, tomorrow you will see log file with date created (change of date)

Comment: are you saying my application.properties is enough and only the second config property would be enough ? Or do I need to keep both ?